# Spark Structured Streaming - testing one batch at a time

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to create a test for a custom `MicroBatchReadSupport` DataSource which I've implemented.

For that, I want to invoke one batch at a time, which will read the data using this DataSource(I've created appropriate mocks). I want to invoke a batch, verify that the correct data was read (currently by saving it to a memory sink and checking the output), and only then invoke the next batch and verify it's output.

I couldn't find a way to invoke each batch after the other.
If I use `streamingQuery.processAllAvailable()`, the batches are invoked one after the other, without allowing me to verify the output for each one separately. Using `trigger(Trigger.Once())` doesn't help as well, because it executes one batch and I can't continue to the next one.

Is there any way to do what I want?

Currently this is my basic code:

```
val dataFrame = sparkSession.readStream.format("my-custom-data-source").load()
    val dsw: DataStreamWriter[Row] = dataFrame.writeStream
      .format("memory")
      .queryName("test_output")
    val streamingQuery = dsw
      .start()
    streamingQuery.processAllAvailable()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've ended up doing is setting up the test with a DataStreamWriter which runs once, but saves the current status to a checkpoint. So each time we invoke `dsw.start()`, the new batch is resumed from the latest offset, according to the checkpoint. I'm also saving the data into a globalTempView, so I will be able to query the data in a similar way to using the memory sink. For doing that, I'm using `foreachBatch` (which is only available since Spark 2.4).

This is in code:

```
val dataFrame = sparkSession.readStream.format("my-custom-data-source").load()
val dsw = getNewDataStreamWriter(dataFrame)

testFirstBatch(dsw)
testSecondBatch(dsw)

private def getNewDataStreamWriter(dataFrame: DataFrame) = {
    val checkpointTempDir = Files.createTempDirectory("tests").toAbsolutePath.toString
    val dsw: DataStreamWriter[Row] = dataFrame.writeStream
    .trigger(Trigger.Once())
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointTempDir)
    .foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
        batchDF.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView("input_data")
    }
    dsw
}
```

And the actual test code for each batch (e.g. `testFirstBatch`) is:

```
val rows = processNextBatch(dsw)
assertResult(10)(rows.length)

private def processNextBatch(dsw: DataStreamWriter[Row]) = {
    val streamingQuery = dsw
        .start()
    streamingQuery.processAllAvailable()
    sparkSession.sql("select * from global_temp.input_data").collect()
}
```